# Execute a mysql statement in the background

Tags: python, mysql

I have a 'throwaway' sql statement that I would like to run. I don't care about the error status, and I don't need to know if it completed successfully. It is to create an index on a table that is very infrequently used. I currently have the connection and cursor object, and here is how I would normally do it:

```
self.cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (_id)')
```

Easy enough. However, this statement takes about five minutes, and like I mentioned, it's not important enough to block other items that are unrelated to it. Is it possible to execute a `cursor` statement in the background? Again, I don't need any status or anything from it, and I don't care about 'closing the cursor/connection' or anything -- it really is a throw-away statement on a table that is probably accessed one to five times in its lifetime before being dropped.

```
threading.Thread(target=lambda tn, cursor: cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD INDEX (_id)' % tn))).start()
```

What would be the best approach to execute a statement in the background so it doesn't block future sql statements.

Comment: What is the question? "Is it possible to execute a cursor statement in the background?", yes, it is.

Comment: It sounds like you are recreating this table periodically. Why not add the index in the create statement?